# Black shadows appearing from invisible objects only in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

I was going to leave blender rendering an animation overnight and noticed shadows (or black geometry) from invisible objects being visible when they aren't supposed to. How disappointing. Only happens in Cycles. Solution?

Comment: What are the material properties of these objects? Why are they invisible?

Comment: They have the same properties as the one in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIthYMgWM0Q&list=PLetCCBn3bjLwlymgf5hqoqfE3UBaXPUMw&index=60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *Properties Editor  > Render Tab > Light Paths > Max Bounces* subpanel and increase the *Transparent* max bounces until the shadows disappear.